# TypeError: this[e][n] is undefined using jvectomap

Tags: javascript, jvectormap

I'm using jvectormap and I want to unselect a state when I select another, but I have this error

> TypeError: this[e][n] is undefined.

This is part of my code:

```
Selector2 = {
colorBlank : 'white',
selectedColor : '#0D88BC',
oldcode: '',

disable:function(old_code,objMap){
    old_code = String(old_code);
    objMap.setSelectedRegions({old_code:false});
},
select:function(id){
    var mapObj = jQuery('#states-area').vectorMap('get', 'mapObject');
    if(this.oldcode.length != 0){
        _code = this.oldcode;
        this.disable(_code,mapObj);
    }       
    this.oldcode = id;
    stateCode = id;
},
```

The variable `id` is the state's key, and in this line `objMap.setSelectedRegions({old_code:false})` appears the error.
What's wrong? help me please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this line:

```
objMap.setSelectedRegions({old_code:false});
```

Here you set the selection state of the region named `"old_code"`, not the one named after the value in the `old_code` variable. Here are some fixes:

```
// ES6
objMap.setSelectedRegions({[old_code]:false});

// or ES5
var temp = {};
temp[old_code] = false;
objMap.setSelectedRegions(temp);
```